# SQL Query to return result set based on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to return a SQL query that returns a set of results that match multiple criteria, but only returns the distinct results from those criteria.  Here's what I have:

- A set of user IDs matched to a list of items
- Each item has a brand and a rating associated to it
- I'm trying to write one query that returns a list of users that have items with 2 specific brands, BOTH with ratings of 5

Example:

```
user_id     brands     rating  
-------     ------     ------
  1           A          5
  1           B          4
  1           C          5
  2           A          3
  2           C          1
  3           A          5
  3           B          4
  3           C          5
  4           D          3
  4           B          4
  4           C          5
```

I want to return the list of user_ids with items matching Brand A and Brand C where both their ratings are 5.  So the result would be:

```
user_id
-------
  1
  3
```

I've tried a few things, including a SELECT with a Union, but can't get the logic right.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

Select the unique users that have brands A and C and have a rating of 5 for both. You can achieve this by joining the table on itself, providing two different aliases. This way, you can have t1 returning the user for brand A and t2 returning the same user for brand C.

```
select distinct
  t1.user_id
from YourTable t1 
inner join YourTable t2 on t2.user_id = t1.user_id
where
  t1.brands = 'A' and
  t2.brands = 'C' and
  t1.rating = 5 and
  t2.rating = 5
```

Comment: Thanks GolezTrol, that worked perfectly!  Appreciate the help.